# Why my SD card shows "folder is empty" and how to fix?

Tags: filesystems, formatting, storage, sd-card

I recently got an SD card to supplement my laptop's storage capacity. 
However, after moving some files into there, I see that the folders are "empty":
[image]

Interestingly, size is still being taken up:

[image]

Here's some information about the card:
Manufacturer: Samsung
Capacity: 128 GB
Format: microSDXC
Speed Class: 10
File System: exFAT
Allocation unit size: 128 KB

My OS: Windows 10

I am sure this is a relatively simple problem but there are too many SEO-optimised articles out there with ZERO information other than lots of words related to the problem...

They go on and on and eventually say to run:

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
```

... Without saying what is causing the problem or what this command does.
I don't believe in running commands I don't understand well. So, I didn't try it.

Comment: The `attrib` operating system command is saying that everything on the device should be recursively reset of all their special attributes (hidden, read-only, system). If you do not want to run it, then you could first try to see whether there are any kind of hidden files or folders on your device.

Comment: First thing to do with **any** flash drive with a large claimed capacity is check whether that's actually true - https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/ has a number of tools to test.

Comment: SD cards are not dependable and can break easily. I suggest replacing the card.